# Trying to use Xpath to get data from a website but returns empty list

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

So I am trying to pull the APR for each pool off the website below, I am trying to use lxml and the xpath. I am using the xpath helper extension to check that I have the correct Xpath and it seems to be showing that I do but only an empty list is returned. My code I'm using is below.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://polyroll.org/farms'
response = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

xpath = '//div[@class="sc-hmbstg iriXCP"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/text()'
result = tree.xpath(xpath)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like most of the page content is generated by JavaScript. lxml is not a web browser, so you probably need something like Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev/).

Comment: It's better to inspect (right click -> "inspect" on Chrome) requests done when you hit "https://polyroll.org/farms". If you look at those, you will find that most are xhr post requests to "https://matic-mainnet-archive-rpc.bwarelabs.com/", each one returns a json with keys: "jsonrpc" (json rpc version),"id" (probabilly, order) and "result" (hex string, idk what it represents)

Comment: Hence, your problem is not xpath, because the response of your requisition does not contain the data that you're looking for. To get more help, you may want to edit your question in order to be more specific.

Comment: Using selenium did the trick, just needed to wait long enough for the page to load the results of the post requests then could use xpath with no issues. Thanks for the help